# how to pass the key in URI in codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I want to pass a license key in where condition of my sql.

I fetch my keys like this

```
$this->data['keys'] = $this->key_m->get_key();


<?php if(count($keys)): foreach($keys as $key): ?>  
    <tr >

        <td><?php echo anchor('admin/activation/'.$key->id, $key->site_key);   ?></td>
```

Now i am using anchor tag here. 
I want to do something like this:

I have a table called activation which contains the device_id and the key with which it is activated.

I get all the keys shown up here, where i will have key, company name and num_licenses.

Now when i click on the key,
i want to fetch all the devices that are activated using that key.

I hope you understood  me

Comment: what is the format of your key? Can you provide any sample?

Comment: `if (count($this->data['keys'])){/*do the work*/}`. Change `$keys` with `$this->data['keys']`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to use the link(s) you are generating in your question then this might be the answer.

Assuming the results of anchor are something like this

```
http://example.com/admin/activation/123
```

Then (assuming there is no special routing in place) this is what would recieve that link

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller
{
  public function activation($key)
  {
   //use $key argument here, which in this example is equal to 123 
  }

}
```